# How to call two functions in a setInterval callback within the useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, react-hooks

I am running setInterval in the useEffect hook to run two functions consecutively, however, only the first function loops. What do I need to do to get the first function to run followed by the second?

I have even tried having two setInterval functions running and changing their delay options to try and simulate the consecutive behavior I am looking for. But it glitches and it is quite obvious that there is a problem with my text effect.

```
   const myText = props.text;
  const textTimeout = props.textDelay;
  const funTextInterval = (textTimeout * myText.length) + 200;
  const [quickText, setQuickText] = useState([]);

  const displayFunText = (i) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      myFunction1();
    }, textTimeout * i);
  };

  const erraseFunText = (j) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      myFunction2();
    }, textTimeout * j);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const loop = () => {
      for (let i = 0; i < myText.length + 1; i += 1) {
        displayFunText(i);
      }
    };

    const reverseLoop = () => {
      for (let j = myText.length; j > 0; j -= 1) {
        erraseFunText(j);
      }
    };

    loop();
    const callLoops = () => {
      reverseLoop();
      loop();
    };

    const runLoops = useInterval(() => {
      callLoops();
    }, funTextInterval);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(runLoops);
    };
  }, []);
```

I expect the `reverseLoop()` to run first then `loop()` to run after, but I am not getting that effect.

Comment: `setTimeout` does not stop the execution, so all your loops run immediately without any waiting. This kind of thing is easier to do with promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that your time out delays for erasing effects are shorter than the longest delay for the display effect. Realise that the timeouts for the display and the erasing effect are executed all in one go, so the delays should keep increasing if you want the callbacks (myFunction1, myFunction2) to be executed in proper order.

Here is how it could work. Comments denote where I had to make corrections:

```js
// Extra code to define the functions/variables which you did not provide (ignore it):
const output = document.querySelector("div");
const myFunction1 = () => output.textContent = myText.slice(0, output.textContent.length+1);
const myFunction2 = () => output.textContent = myText.slice(0, output.textContent.length-1);
const props = { text: "This is a test", textDelay: 100 };
const useEffect = (cb) => cb();
const useState = () => [];
const useInterval = setInterval;
// END extra code

const myText = props.text;
const textTimeout = props.textDelay;
const funTextInterval = (textTimeout * myText.length * 2) + 200; // 2 times (show+hide)!
const [quickText, setQuickText] = useState([]);

const displayFunText = (i) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        myFunction1();
    }, textTimeout * i);
};

const erraseFunText = (j) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        myFunction2();
    }, textTimeout * j);
};

useEffect(() => {
    const loop = () => {
        for (let i = 0; i < myText.length; i += 1) { // fix end-condition
            displayFunText(i);
        }
    };

    const reverseLoop = () => {
        for (let j = myText.length; j < 2*myText.length; j += 1) { // fix to produce greater values (= delays)
            erraseFunText(j);
        }
    };

    const callLoops = () => { // change order:
        loop();
        reverseLoop();
    };

    callLoops(); // instead of loop()

    const runLoops = useInterval(() => {
        callLoops();
    }, funTextInterval);

    return () => {
        clearInterval(runLoops);
    };
}, []);
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

You may want to look into promises and `async` functions, which might make this kind of asynchrony easier to work with (opinions differ).