# Material-UI Consecutive Animations

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have 2 divs.

First `div` becomes visible with `Material-UI` `Slide` animation, then second `div` becomes visible with `Grow` animation after the first `div` is gone.*(I'm using setInterval)*

I set the active `div` with `Hooks`. Unfortunately after setting the first `div` inactive, the second `div` becomes visible immediately and I cannot show the `exit` animation of the first `div`.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55926514/how-to-call-two-functions-in-a-setinterval-callback-within-the-useeffect-hook) question but could not implement it, it's over complicated.

```
export default function BasicTable() {
    const classes = useStyles();

    const [firstScreenActive, setFirstScreenActive] = React.useState(true);
    
    //I don't use this hook right now.
    const [secondScreenActive, setSecondScreenActive] = React.useState(false);

    const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(1);

    useEffect(() => {
        const timer = setInterval(() => {
            setSeconds(seconds + 1);
            setFirstScreenActive((prev) => !prev);
        }, 4000);
        return () => clearInterval(timer);
    });

    return (
        <div className={styles.main}>

            {!firstScreenActive ?

                <div className={styles.cardPerson}>
                    <Grow
                        in={!firstScreenActive}
                        style={{ transformOrigin: '0 0 0' }}
                        {...(!firstScreenActive ? { timeout: 1000 } : {})}
                    >
                        <div className={styles.cardPersonItem}>
                        </div>
                    </Grow>
                </div>

                :

                <div className={styles.cardPerson}>
                    <Slide direction='right' in={firstScreenActive} mountOnEnter unmountOnExit timeout={{ enter: 980, exit: 400 }}>
                        <TableContainer className={classes.body} component={Paper}>
                        </TableContainer>
                    </Slide>
                </div>
            }
        </div >
    );
}
```

How can I show the exit animations?(for both `divs`)

Edit:

SandBox with my whole view. [Click](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-045t2?file=/demo.js).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `firstScreenActive ?` from `return` and add `unmountOnExit` and `mountOnEnter` props on `Grow`

Here is the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-w7fom?file=/demo.js)

Animation will display when you remove `firstScreenActive` check

updated [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-ptc09?file=/demo.js:6788-6817)

Comment: I really appriacte you efforts, thank you for your time. With your solution, `Slide` `div` goes to out of the screen. Maybe it happens because my view is more complicated than I posted. I forked your `SandBox' and paste my whole view. Can you check it out? Link is in the post.

Comment: sure let me check it

Comment: I have updated the code. I have also update some of the styles. 
Please check it

Comment: First view appears at the bottom of the screen before the second view leaves. I changed `Grow` to `Slide`, also I changed the `enter` and `exit` times but no chance.